# Splitting Comma Delimited String into Multiple New Strings

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

I have a comma delimited string which I'd like to split (I know how this can be accomplished - there are plenty of resources on this) but then I'd like to take the new split values and use them as strings themselves.

For Example

```
Oldstring = "user,game,demo,points,level"

NewString0 = user

NewString1 = game

NewString2 = demo 

NewString3 = points

NewString4 = level
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String[] newStrings = oldstring.split(",")`

Now use the [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

```
NewString0 = newStrings[0];

NewString1 = newStrings[1];

NewString2 = newStrings[2];

NewString3 = newStrings[3];

NewString4 = newStrings[4];
```

Comment: Exactly as I have it implemented above? : )

Comment: you can use String s =newStrings[index] with the index

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `StringTokenizer`.

```
       String newString[]=new String[10];
       StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(oldString,",");
        for (int i = 0; str.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
         newString[i]=str.nextToken();
        }
```

Hope it will be helpful. :)